# Boldsymbol in subsection title

Tags: sectioning, boldsymbol, mathrm

I'm using the following command in my text and there is no problem, but it doesn't work in the subsection title,

```
\boldsymbol{\mathrm{tr}}
```

---

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx, arydshln, algorithm}
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
My contents ...
\subsection{Trace ($\boldsymbol{\mathrm{tr}}(W_c)$)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very definite, show the error message that you get, it runs without error and makes a bold tr in texlive 2109 (you could simply use `\mathbf` rather than `\boldsymbol{\mathrm`

Comment: For me, this code works. Just in case, try a simpler `\mathbf{tr}`which produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks guys. I get this error:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. T

Comment: that's very weird, you get that error on the document exactly as posted above? I tried in texlive 2016 and 2019 with no error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I also use texlive 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't make "tr" **bold**. The `IEEEtran` document class doesn't typeset subsection-level headers in bold; why use bold for parts of the formula, then?  Instead, I'd define (and use) a math operator called `\tr`.

[image]

If you simply *must* typeset "tr" in **bold**, I suggest you change `\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}` to `\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{\mathbf{tr}}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, xcolor, enumerate, 
            amsthm, graphicx, arydshln, algorithm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
\section{Main}
My contents \dots
\subsection{Trace of the Controllability Gramian Matrix, $\tr(W_{\!c})$}
\end{document}
```